# How can I this fix covariance issue with Action on .NET 2?

Tags: c#, .net, covariance

I need to create a covariant interface with a method that takes a delegate with covariant generic parameter. Here's the code sample under question:

```
interface IExample<out T1>
{
    void ExampleMethod(Action<T1> someAction);
}
```

On Mono/ .NET 4 profile it compiles OK (tested it in Xamarin studio). However, on .NET 2 (which I'm forced to use since I'm using Unity game engine), I get the following error:

> error CS1961: The covariant type parameter 'T1' must be invariantly valid on `CovarianceExample.IExample.ExampleMethod(System.Action)'

Why does this error occur in early .Net versions? How can I fix it?

Comment: While I use Unity game engine, I don't think that I should add unity3d tag, since this question has nothing specific for Unity in particular, and can be useful for someone stuck with earlier versions of .Net for other reasons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why does this error occur in early .Net versions?

Because `Action` wasn't contravariant in .NET 2.0 (or 3.5).

> How can I fix it?

Don't use .NET 2.0 :) I thought that modern versions of Unity were based on more recent versions of Mono anyway - perhaps an upgrade is available?

Alternatively, you could declare your own `ContravariantAction` delegate:

```
public delegate void ContravariantAction<in T>(T value);
```

I haven't tried doing so against .NET 2.0, but I believe the appropriate attributes were already present, and at least the MS .NET implementation supported generic variance - it just wasn't exposed in C# or used in the BCL.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! It took some time to get it working properly though, but it's not related to the question itself (I had an event field, and using it inside a covariant class resulted in cryptic exceptions in runtime).